# Windows error within shutil when moving a file

Tags: python

I have a python script which aims to rename pdf files based on specific content of the pdf.  I am having trouble when the content is not found.  The aim is to move that file to a new folder to be manually renamed.

I get windows permission error 32 from within shutil.

I have checked that the file is not open in any apps.
I closed all apps except pycharm.
I have no other projects open.

This is the section of code related to the file:

```
    # Scan all files in the origin directory
    for filename in os.listdir(origin_directory):
        # Get file path
        file_path = os.path.join(origin_directory, filename)
        print('line 34 ' + f"File path: {file_path}")
    
        # Open file for reading
    #    with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as file:
    #    with fitz.open(os.path.join(origin_directory, filename), "r") as doc:
        with fitz.open(os.path.join(origin_directory, filename), ) as doc:
            print("line 42")
            found_Inv_no = False
            # Iterate through each line
            for line in doc:
                try:
                    text = line.get_text("utf-8")
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    print(f"Warning: Unable to decode line content using utf-8: {line}")
                    continue  # Skip to the next line
                # Check for any of the search terms
                for term in invoice_no_search_terms:
                    if term in line.get_text("utf-8"):
                        # Extract numbers after the term (on the same line)
                        match = re.findall(r"\d+", line[line.find(term):], re.IGNORECASE)
                        invoice_numbers.extend(match)
                        found_Inv_no = True
                        print("line 58")
                        fitz.close(doc)
                        break
    
    
            # No search terms found, move file to holding directory
    
            if not found_Inv_no:
                doc.close()  # Close the pdf file being read before moving
                moved_name=("moved " + filename)
                print (moved_name)
                new_file_path = os.path.join(holding_Directory, moved_name)
                print(f"Moving file from {file_path} to {new_file_path}")
                shutil.move(file_path, new_file_path)
                print("done")
                print(filename)
```

So, i have shutil moving and renaming the file successfully.
The print statements confirm that the for loop is not working and it is breaking down with fitz.  It seems that the previous filename is being used by fitz but I don't know how to verify this.
the new error message is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AdamYates\PycharmProjects\RenamePdfmaster\ReanemPDFMaster.py", line 41, in 
with fitz.open(os.path.join(origin_directory, filename), ) as doc:
File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\RenamePdf.venv\Lib\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 5893, in **exit**
self.close()
File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\RenamePdf.venv\Lib\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 5874, in close
raise ValueError("document closed")
ValueError: document closed

Comment: What is `Work U Drive`?  Is that a local directory, or is it some kind of shortcut to cloud storage?

Comment: Did you try `fitz.close(doc)` before `break`?

Comment: Work U Drive is merely part of the file path as a local directory.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic is pretty clear.

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Adobe Acrobat or another reader is holding a read lock on the source file.
Close the document, or kill the reader process, to release the lock.
An unlocked file will be successfully moved in the usual way.

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  It does this to every file.  I've checked that each file to be it is not write protected in Acrobat. When I run the code everything is closed except pycharm.   the only process that is dealing with this file is the python code.  I've even rebooted the PC.  I wonder if Fitz is not closing? I've added the whole code to the question.